# How to handle huge data response from server in android

Tags: android

I am using eclipse ADT for my android development. let me explain my problem. I can receive the response from my server api, the problem is, the data is very huge and am unable to display entire response in my logcat. I used AsynTask for getting response. 
 DoinBackground method

```
getBookingResults = ServerConnection.getbookings(
                BookingsActivity.this, Utils.URL + "users/"
                        + "123145/" + "subscribed");
```

This is my Get() in separate class

```
public static String getData(Context ctx, String uri) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        try {
            Log.d("Serverconnection URL ", uri);
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(200000);

            // save status code
            Utils.statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
            // String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.d("server connection getData", "" + sb.toString());

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.d("server connection getData Error ", "" + e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return " ";

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return " ";
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

When i am checking the response string in my logcat is shows string length 11743. The logcat is not displaying entire response

Help me out to handle huge data response

Thanks in advance

Comment: ask google for: "logcat character limit" or "logcat string limit"

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that you cannot blindly allocate all the data from server otherwise risk of OOM is very high. You should use technique similar to what android suggests with list, keep in memory only those elements visible to user. In other words, first you have to figure out what the size is or expect that size may be huge. Then load data chunk by chunk to some UI element and implement some kind of "load by scroll". In case you cannot load from the net as you scroll, perhaps due to nature of the connection, then you should load chunk by chunk and save the data to local store. And then display it chunk by chunk as described above. This is how I would do it. Sorry, not exactly the answer you look for.